# Array value restriction by class inheritance

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm writing signal processing library,
and I want to make this kind of hierarchy.

First, I defined `abstract class`
that define only "this wrapper class has one `double[]` field"
i.e.

```
public abstract class DoubleArray{
    private final double[] array;
    DoubleArray(double[] array){
        this.array = array;
    }
}
```

(I made constructor `package private` rather than `protected` because
I want to restrict usage of constructor outside the package)

(`System.arraycopy` is not used here
because this constructor is used only by me.)

Next, my first restriction is,
"cannot contain exceptional values"
i.e.

```
//inside the same package
public class SignalWithoutExceptionalValues extends DoubleArray{
    SignalWithoutExceptionalValues(double[] signal){
        super(signal);
        for(double d : signal)
            if(Double.isNaN(d) || Double.isInfinite(d))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot contain exceptional values");
    }
}
```

Next restriction is
"signal is in range of -1.0 ~ 1.0"
i.e.

```
//inside the same package
public final class OneAmplitudeSignal extends SignalWithoutExceptionalValues{
    OneAmplitudeSignal(double[] signal){
        super(signal);
        for(double d : signal)
            if(d > 1.0 || d < -1.0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("is not normalized");
    }
}
```

However, I think,
first of all,
I have to do `for-each` argument checking,
and then, after that,
assign to field.

but in this example,
I am forced to assign unchecked array to field,
because `DoubleArray` constructor must initialize `array` field.

So, my question is,
is there any strategy to do "**first checking then assign**"
in this kind of hierarchy.
**OR** this design is not appropriate for this purpose,
and there is another good design ?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

thank you for first two answers.
but by those solution,
library user can instantiate "illegal" signal,
because "checking mechanism can be overrided" .

However, I perfer inheritance
because `OneAmplitudeSignal` object can be
assigned to `SignalWithoutExceptionalValues` variables.
This fact corresponds to `OneAmp~` is **subset** of `SignalWithout~`.

Also, amplitude can be checked by `someSignal instanceof OneAmplitudeSignal` .

And "`final`" can't be used here
because I want to allow library users
to create new "**more restricted signal**"
or, "**new kind of restriction**" .

In addition, root class can be `non-abstract` .
in this case, "no restriction signal" can also be instantiated.

Comment: By the way, `MinusOneToOneSignal` is more appropriate.  Is there more simple name?

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the checking logic to a separate `check` method which the base constructor can execute prior to the assignment :

```
public abstract class DoubleArray{
    private final double[] array;
    protected abstract void check (double[] array);
    DoubleArray(double[] array){
        check(array);
        this.array = array;
    }
}
```

The sub-classes will override `check` to supply the required validation logic :

```
public class SignalWithoutExceptionalValues extends DoubleArray{
    SignalWithoutExceptionalValues(double[] signal){
        super(signal);
    }

    @Override
    protected void check (double[] signal) {
        for(double d : signal)
            if(Double.isNaN(d) || Double.isInfinite(d))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot contain exceptional values");
    }
}

public final class OneAmplitudeSignal extends SignalWithoutExceptionalValues{
    OneAmplitudeSignal(double[] signal){
        super(signal);
    }

    @Override
    protected void check (double[] signal) {
        super.check ();
        for(double d : signal)
            if(d > 1.0 || d < -1.0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("is not normalized");
    }
}
```

Comment: @ShuS Be ware that with this solution `OneAmplitudeSignal` is extending `SignalWithoutExceptionalValues` (and not `DoubleArray`) and requires that you don't forget to call `super.check()` (same applies if you have more rules) !

Comment: @Spotted    I see .   Then,  this implementation can't be used , because I can't force library user to call `super.check()` . Is there another solution ?  One thing I can think of is, to have `boolean` flag `isNormalized` , but I prefer inheritance because `OneAmplitudeSignal` is apparently subset of `SignalWithout~` .

Answer (score 0):

Since you are writing a library, it means that your library could be used in some cases you can't predict now. That's why I would avoid using inheritance because with inheritance you are scealing (enforcing) what you think is right in order to validate a signal by this static inheritance chain: `OneAmplitudeSignal` > `SignalWithoutExceptionalValues` > `DoubleArray`.

I would instead foster composition to do the validation. This is one possible implementation (more generic):

```
public interface Rule {
    DoublePredicate getPredicate();
    String getReason();
}

public final class ExceptionalValue implements Rule {
    @Override
    public DoublePredicate getPredicate() {
        return d -> Double.isNaN(d) || Double.isInfinite(d);
    }

    @Override
    public String getReason() {
        return "cannot contain exceptional values";
    }
}

public final class GreaterThanOneAmplitude implements Rule {
    @Override
    public DoublePredicate getPredicate() {
        return d -> d > 1.0 || d < -1.0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getReason() {
        return "is not normalized";
    }
}

public final class DoubleArray {
    private final double[] array;

    public DoubleArray(double[] signal, Collection<Rule> rules) {
        for (Rule rule : rules) {
            if (Arrays.stream(signal).anyMatch(rule.getPredicate())) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(rule.getReason());
            }
        }

        this.array = signal;
    }

    //...
}
```

On the other hand, if you don't need to (or want to) be generic simply do that:

```
public final class DoubleArray {
    private final double[] array;

    public DoubleArray(double[] signal) {
        for(double d : signal) {
            if(Double.isNaN(d) || Double.isInfinite(d)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot contain exceptional values");
            }
            if(d > 1.0 || d < -1.0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("is not normalized");
            }
        }

        this.array = signal;
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: your implementation is smart, but I want to check amplitude by   "`someSignal instanceof OneAmplitudeSignal`" .

Comment: @ShuS Not sure I understand correctly what you want to do with `instanceof`. Using `instanceof` is a sign of poor design and leads to maintanability problems.